# Git 'post-receive' deploy hook - exclude directory on server

Tags: git, deployment, githooks, git-post-receive

I'm trying to store images locally on my server and can't figure out how to prevent my deploy script from overriding the directory they are stored in (/public/local-images).

The --exclude= tag doesn't seem to work, or I'm writing the path/expression incorrectly.

If I add (local-images/) to my local .gitignore file then every deploy will replace the entire remote file system, deleting the /public/local-images directory on the server.

```
#!/bin/sh

WEB_DIR=/opt/erinauc

# remove any untracked files and directories
git --work-tree=${WEB_DIR} clean -fd --exclude=/opt/erinauc/public/local-images/

# force checkout of the latest deploy
git --work-tree=${WEB_DIR}  checkout -f

pm2 restart erinauc
```

I think this should be simple. I'm confused, and frustrated.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: is `public/local-images` the actual path on your server? you might need the path to be `--exclude=public/local-images/` or possibly a full path could work as well using your `WEB_DIR`, like  `--exclude=${WEB_DIR}/public/local-images/`

Comment: Hi @DavidUlrich , I think you're right about the absolute path being the proper formatting, but I just tried that and still no success. Thanks anyways.